# fsync on mapped crypted device with dm-crypt?

Tags: c, encryption, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, luks

I have a question about dm-crypt.

Here is my situation. I have an encrypted partition mapped (encrypted in virtual device) using the cryptsetup command in Linux. I am opening the mapped virtual device in a c-program using the open() function.

Can i be sure that when i use the fsync() function all information will be written to the encrypted partition or is there some buffer in the dm-crypt driver?

Comment: Is this a question about dm-crypt in general (whether it buffers before writing even after a `sync`), or do you think that using your own program is different from for example a shell command, say, a `touch crypt/file; sync`?

Comment: I use own program on C. But cryptsetup use dm-crypt kernel module to map crypted partition in /dev/mapper/<device_name> witch I open into C program with open() and write and read directly. And my question is when i call fsync() into my C program all info witch i write before will be into real crypted partition after fsync() return or is there a way to be into buffer in dm-crypt module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find much reference on this. Maybe someone can shed more light on this, as I have not grokked [the source](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/tree/master), but it seems as though a `sync` writes to disk.

One point is the questions [trim-with-lvm-and-dm-crypt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85865/trim-with-lvm-and-dm-crypt) where a `sync` changes the **disk content reliably**, yet the cached content is only updated after a `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

Another is [the issue](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/issues/207) that `sync` hangs on a suspended device, which indicates that the sync goes directly to the device.

A third is this [Gentoo discussion](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6925154.html#6925154) where `luksClose` is possible reliably after a `sync`.

A fourth is [this UL answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163294/115933), which says

> the rest of the stuff [dm-crypt] is in kernel and pretty heavily used, so it's
>   probably fine

It may still be that all these are wrong, and it can happen that `sync` does not write directly to the encrypted disk, but it seems unlikely.